# Firebase push notification iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

iOS app gets firebase push when I launch it debug it on iPhone from my Mac. But when I uploaded app to itunes connect and it's available for sales I install it to Iphone from Appstore then app doesn't get any push notifications. In what the problem can be?

```
AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm_message_id"

override init() {
    //Firebase configurations
    FIRApp.configure()

    //caching from firebase
    //FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Notifications
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)

    //remove badge number
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0


    return true
}


// [START refresh_token]
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    connectToFcm()

    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {

        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        guard let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else {return}
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user").child(user.uid).child("pushToken")
        ref.setValue(refreshedToken)

    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

}

// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
}

// [START connect_on_active]
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
}
// [END connect_on_active]

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

//    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) 
{
//        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user 
data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
//        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
//    }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

//    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
//        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
//    }

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)


    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]

}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
 @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }


    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)


}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
@escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }


    print(userInfo)
    // Print full message.

}
}
 // [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

Comment: Are you sure your App ID has Push Notifications for Distribution enabled?

Comment: @Devhess yes of course

Comment: I have the opposite issue

Comment: Have you uploaded the appropriate production certificate on Firebase's console ?